# Long URL in SharePoint for URL type Field

Tags: url

I have a long URL and it's not fitting in the URL field. It keeps trimming. What to do? Is there a way to increase the URL field characters limit in SharePoint 2010?

Or a work around to accommodate long URL. For example, the following URL wont fit in current URL field.

http://Intranet.CollegeEducation.Edu/StudentCourses/Year/2013/_layouts/CustomForms/FormRender.aspx?List={FBB7EE62-BC6E-42A2-8458-92AF56B063A1}&RootFolder=/StudentCourses/Year/2013/CourseChangeRequest&ContentTypeId=0x0101008C18BC49FB564DD891D01B108399315A01003B9EF9111179DF4E99CD24C2C0391DDD&Source=/StudentCourses/Year/2013

Comment: Generally speaking SP has a URL limit of 255 characters. See the answer to this post for a better explanation: [255 URL character limit in 2010](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointgeneralprevious/thread/b76e543a-f777-4277-829c-821c670f1e8c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the workaround for your situation.

1. Add a Multi-Text column to your list
2. Edit the item that has long URL
3. Go to the Multi-Text field and you will get Rich-Content Ribbon
4. Click Insert on the Ribbon > Hyperlink
5. Add your Title and long URL in the respected field

Wala you are done.